# What heuristics are used in NavMeshes?

Tags: path-finding

What heuristics do programmers use in A* pathfinding for NavMeshes?

NavMesh = Navigation Mesh, its a type of pathfinding that uses meshes instead of waypoints.

Comment: Please clarify your question. I don't know what you mean when you say "NavMeshes" (capitalized as if it's a Product Name™). Are you asking for alternative algorithms to A* which produce more approximate paths but in faster time?

Comment: @Ricket http://www.ai-blog.net/archives/000152.html

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I've heard of them but never done anything with them so I didn't recognize the condensed name :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take your pick:

http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html

There's a load of heuristics described in that link, either for speed or accuracy. There's always a trade-off, so I would assume that developers would use the most accurate heuristic that would cause minimal impact to their game's performance.

Comment: These are for grid maps. Nav meshes I assume would use a different heuristics to move from one poly to the other. Probably some form of geometry heuristic to select the next best poly based on the size of the edge or something.

Comment: Agreed, but heuristics are used to estimate the shortest path to the final absolute destination to help with the cost to the next poly. They should underestimate the distance to be an "admissable heuristic". A navigation mesh is still a graph, just like a grid map is a graph. So I reckon most of those heuristics are applicable, it's down to the developer to see which is most applicable.

Answer (score 1):

A very, very rough (but very speedy) heuristic to use is: (Manhattan distance)

```
vec1 = start vector
vec2 = end vector

heuristic = abs(vec2.x - vec1.x) + abs(vec2.y - vec1.y))
```

This avoids any square rooting, which could be costly (Pythagorean distance).

Comment: Manhattan distance, no?

Comment: I thought it was, then edited it out since I though it might not have been.

Comment: You could also use the squared length (Pythagorean distance without taking the square root). It's fast and most likely a better heuristic than Manhattan distance (unless your character can only move horizontally and vertically)

Comment: @bummzack: Please read the "Euclidean distance, squared" section of Amit's heuristic page. Distance squared is not an admissible heuristic, and will result in suboptimal pathing.

Comment: Squared distances are too small for short distances (A* wastes time) and too large for long distances (A* finds worse paths). There are good reasons to have the heuristic overestimate distances, but avoiding sqrt isn't one of them. Either use a fast sqrt approximation, or use a diagonal distance, or if your navigation graph is explicit, compute the Euclidean/Pythagorean distance once and store it with the edge between nodes.